# Members Web Part

Tags: web-part

Is there a mechanism to add additional columns to the Members WebPart?

Currently we see only UserName.

I would like profile pic and other stuff that is available via the Contact List.

Comment: Do You usw so 2010 or sp2013?

Comment: Sp2013 visual studio 2012